# Terraform Api Gateway Lambda Integration trigger problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

If I manually add an Integration Request of type Lambda function, an Api Gateway trigger is automatically added to the lambda function.

If I do it via Terraform, everything looks correct but when I go look at the Lambda function it has no trigger.

If I then manually update the Integration Request (change to Mock and back to Lambda Function) the trigger is added to the Lambda function? Everything works after that.

What am I missing?

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  count = var.lambda_definition.apigateway ? 1 : 0
  rest_api_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.apigateway.outputs.apigateway_id}"
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_proxy_resource[count.index].id
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.method[count.index].http_method}"
  integration_http_method = "ANY"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.lambda.invoke_arn
}
```

Comment: I'm using `aws_apigatewayv2_api` resource and I found out that the issue is simply that I didn't have the `target` argument on it. `target = aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn` is the **LIFE SAVER!** [_Source here._](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-the-aws-apigatewayv2-api-to-add-an-http-api-to-a-lambda-function/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you've not mentioned whether you specified proper **permissions** for your function, my guess is that you are missing [aws_lambda_permission](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission). This will **explicitly give permissions** for the api to invoke your function.

The resource would be (example only):

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_api" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIgatewayInvokation"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda.invoke_arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
}
```

When you do it manually in console, the AWS setups all these permissions in the background.

Comment: Please use `.function_name` instead of `.invoke_arn` as the latter could fail the naming restrictions ("function_name" cannot be longer than 140 characters; "function_name" doesn't comply with [regex] restrictions).

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that `integration_http_method` is set to `POST` and not to `ANY` as in your sample:

```
  integration_http_method = "POST"
```

See [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) - midway - red box that says '! Important':

> For Lambda integrations, you must use the HTTP method of POST for the integration request, according to the specification of the Lambda service action for function invocations. The IAM role of apigAwsProxyRole must have policies allowing the apigateway service to invoke Lambda functions. For more information about IAM permissions, see API Gateway permissions model for invoking an API.

Comment: I was facing the same problem. I had said integration_http_method to GET. The integration method for lambda always needs to be POST. The individual HTTP method under aws_api_gateway_method.http_method can be GET, PUT, POST etc based on the REST API method. Thanks!