# Terraform API Gateway Not Showing Up As Trigger For Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/lambda-api-gateway) for setting up a gateway and a lambda but it does not work. The symptoms appear to be the same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625888/terraform-api-gateway-lambda-integration-trigger-problem) but the fixes suggested there did not work.

My infrastructure definition is as follows:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "lambda_api" {
    name          = "${upper(var.project)}-${upper(var.environment)}-${var.gateway_name}"
    protocol_type = "HTTP"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "lambda_default" {
    name        = "$default"
    api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api.lambda_api.id
    auto_deploy = true
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "gateway_to_lambda" {
    api_id                 = aws_apigatewayv2_api.lambda_api.id
    integration_type       = "AWS_PROXY"
    connection_type        = "INTERNET"
    integration_method     = "POST"
    integration_uri        = aws_lambda_function.executable.arn
    payload_format_version = "2.0"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "route" {
    api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.lambda_api.id
    route_key = "GET /profile"
    target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.gateway_to_lambda.id}"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "execution_lambda_from_gateway" {
    statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = aws_lambda_function.executable.function_name
    principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

    source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.lambda_api.arn}/*/*"
}
```

On the gateway side it looks like things are created correctly: I have an integration that connects my path 'profile' to the lambda:
[image]

However, when I look on the lambda the trigger is missing:
[image]

When I try to hit the endpoint I get an "internal server error" message.

When I manually add the trigger in my lambda then it works but not under the 'profile' route key that I specified.

What am I missing here to correctly route my /profile in the API Gateway to my lambda?

Comment: Can you please remove `source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.lambda_api.arn}/*/*"` and try again? Also if you setup this manually, you can verify the correct permissions that AWS console creates automatically for you.

Comment: Removing the source_arn worked. I didn't have to touch permissions so looks like they where correct. Perhaps I'm expecting the wrong thing but in the Function Overview I still don't see the gateway as a trigger? Is this a UI bug or is trigger in this context something else?

Comment: But the API works? The lambda AWS trigger display is not perfect. As long as API works, you shoudn't worry about AWS console display.

Comment: Yes the API works. TY!
Now onto making authorizer and CORS work...

Comment: Glad it worked. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Comment: @Marcin Could you provide an explanation as to WHY this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments. The solution was to **modify the permissions** (remove `source_arn`):

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "execution_lambda_from_gateway" {
    statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = aws_lambda_function.executable.function_name
    principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
}
```

Comment: Removing the permissions was not the fix. The fix was to remove the source_arn.

Comment: @PrzemekLach That's what I wrote. Your new permissions do not have `source_arn`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the source arn from your permission is not the correct answer - FIXING the source arn is the correct solution. You are specifying the `arn` of the gateway when you should be specifying the `execution_arn` instead.

> source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.lambda_api.arn}/*/*"

Should be:

> source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.lambda_api.execution_arn}/*/*"

By removing the `source_arn =`  entirely you open up the lambda to be invoked by any(?) api-gateway which is probably a security issue.

If the permission is correctly set up - you WILL see the gateway as a trigger in the lambda AWS console.

Comment: This is the correct solution. You have to specify the execution_arn for the API Gateway instance.